# python can not find the fits file when using sys.path.insert

Tags: python, python-3.x, sys

I would like to access the output of another python program that extracts information from a fits file.

I usually do this in the following way:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '/software/xray/Python_scripts')
from program2 import results
```

However, in this case, I receive the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'info.fits'
```

When I run the `program2.py` It runs without problem. So, I don't understand why when I call it from `program1.py` it does not recognize the fits file, therefore it doesn't give the results! Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: please provide further info about `program2.py` and the directory structure.

Comment: `sys.path.insert(1, '/software/xray/Python_scripts')` is really not the right way of going about this. But l can only surmise that `program2` uses some sort of relative path to a file `info.fits` because it is assuming that you are running the program like this: `python program2.py` in that working directory. But now, your working directory is wherever you are running your new python script from. To confirm, try something like `import os; os.chdir('/software/xray/Python_scripts')` before you try to `from program2 import results`. note, don't use this as a *solution* even if it works

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for your guide. Yes Program 1 that I am running is in a different location than the program2 (and fits file). When I try your suggestion it says No module named 'program2'. What kind of suggestion do you have for this problem? What is the best approach? I am bit new to python.

Comment: @SaraKrauss wait, is says that when you still have `sys.path.insert(1, '/software/xray/Python_scripts')`? I didn't mean to *remove* that.

Comment: To deal with the issue properly (for now, just keep using the `sys.path` hack) you want to make `program2` an installable package and then install it. Ideally, you should be creating a virtual environment for each project, so you would install it to that environment.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your import `from program2 import results` searching for a file named `info.fits` which is located most probably in `'/software/xray/Python_scripts'`.

Basically, `sys.path.insert` temporarily adds path to `PATH`, in order to make OS executing/importing script from that place. It doesn't mean that it becomes a file search path as well.

You need to do somethig like:

```
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()
os.chdir('/software/xray/Python_scripts')
from program2 import results
os.chdir(cwd)
```

It is certainly a crunch, I would suggest you to create a package out of your program2 module. https://realpython.com/python-modules-packages/

Comment: Thanks. I am receiving an error that states No module named 'program2'. Program 1 that I am running is in a different location than the program2 (and fits file). Also, can you give a bit more detail on how to create a package. That link does not explain it well. Do I have to create a separate python program and call  __init__.py?